# Extending trial version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on-premise

Tags: installation, microsoft-dynamics

Is it even possible to extend a trial version of Dynamics CRM 2016 on premise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend a 90 days OnPremise trial, however you can reinstall all again from scratch